# Update issue with stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working with a Old tool and the database that was connected to this tool in long gone. I am new at this and need some help understanding this. I need help with writing the code i tried and error-ed out every time.

```
public void UpdateUser(string NewUser, string OldUser)
{
using (SqlConnection con = HSDatabaseConnection())
{
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateNames", con))
{
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LogonName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = NewUser;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OldLogonName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = OldUser;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
con.Close();
}
}
```

I have 4 tables the only thing each table has in common is the column name "AN". I need to update "AN" if a agent changes there name legally

so far I have come up with this procedure

```
USE [HSDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[UpdateNames]    Script Date: 9/16/2016 12:32:33 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateNames]
--Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@AN varchar(MAX)

AS
BEGIN
--SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
--interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
--Insert statements for procedure here
UPDATE Att
SET AN = @AN 
WHERE (AN = @AN)
UPDATE MS
SET AN = @AN 
WHERE (AN = @AN)
UPDATE Lost
SET AN = @AN 
WHERE (AN = @AN)
UPDATE WeeklyCharges
SET AN = @AN 
WHERE (AN = @AN)


END
```

Can some one please tell me what i am doing wrong. Thank you

Comment: `SET AN = @AN WHERE AN = @AN`.  This is doing nothing.  You are setting it to the same value.

Comment: Do you really need varchar(max)? Surely your logon names are less than 8,000 characters.

Comment: But I am curious. Why are you trying to fix some code when there is no database? Are you trying to reverse engineer a database from the application code? That seems like it is highly likely to be nearly impossible to get it right. And seriously storing the full name in multiple tables is just awful. It should be normalized to a single point of entry.

Comment: I am reverse engeenering the program to make the database. I need to update myltiple incase there are multiple items. We check out headsets to agent and there is loaners as well as beoken headsets that are assinged to some agents. We need to have them updated on all table they are listed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue 1:
your c# code is passing 2 paramaters @LogonName and @OldLogonName but your stored procedure is only accepting 1 parameter @AN.  So that should error out.

Issue 2:
all of your update statements are setting AN = to itself because you are saying when AN = @AN then set AN = @AN....

Without having more detail about the error and your data structures, which you should include in the future, it is a little difficult to say.  However, you probably could do something like this in SQL-Server 2012 +:

```
USE [HSDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[UpdateNames]    Script Date: 9/16/2016 12:32:33 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateNames]
--Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@LogonName varchar(100)
,@OldLogonName varchar(100)

AS
BEGIN
--SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
--interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
--Insert statements for procedure here
BEGIN TRY

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM LogOnOrUserTable WHERE LogonName = @OldLogonName)
    BEGIN
       ;THROW 51000, 'Old Logon Name Does Not Exists', 1
    END

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    UPDATE Att
    SET AN = @LogonName
    WHERE (AN = @OldLogonName)

    UPDATE MS
    SET AN = @LogonName
    WHERE (AN = @OldLogonName)

    UPDATE Lost
    SET AN = @LogonName
    WHERE (AN = @OldLogonName)

    UPDATE WeeklyCharges
    SET AN = @LogonName
    WHERE (AN = @OldLogonName)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    ;THROW

END CATCH

END
```

What it does:

- first tests to see if the old user name exists and if it doesn't throws an error.
- then updates all of the tables where AN = old logon name and sets it to the new logon name
- if any one of those fails it rolls back the transaction and throws an error so that you don't have a change half made

Comment: @user6840698 seeing my answer worked for you please consider accepting it so that others know it has been answered and for the reputation points to be assigned. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers